# Specified directory or database file does not exist

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have been working on my android projects for years and i am always using this code for database handler to setup sqlite database but these days i installed android studio in new laptop and start to run my projects but i get this error message once app launched:

```
08-26 13:41:51.044 16032-16032/com.nileworx.flagsquiz E/SQLiteLog: (28) failed to open "/data/data/com.nileworx.flagsquiz/databases/FlagsQuiz" with flag (131072) and mode_t (0) due to error (2)
    (14) cannot open file at line 32561 of [a66a5b397b]
    (14) os_unix.c:32561: (2) open(/data/data/com.nileworx.flagsquiz/databases/FlagsQuiz) - 
08-26 13:41:51.054 16032-16032/com.nileworx.flagsquiz E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/com.nileworx.flagsquiz/databases/FlagsQuiz'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 1294): Could not open database
    #################################################################
    Error Code : 1294 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN_ENOENT)
    Caused By : Specified directory or database file does not exist.
        (unknown error (code 1294): Could not open database)
    #################################################################
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:301)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:220)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:512)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:206)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:178)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:908)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:878)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:699)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:674)
        at com.nileworx.flagsquiz.DataBaseHandler.checkDataBase(DataBaseHandler.java:86)
        at com.nileworx.flagsquiz.DataBaseHandler.createDataBase(DataBaseHandler.java:47)
        at com.nileworx.flagsquiz.DAO.<init>(DAO.java:52)
        at com.nileworx.flagsquiz.CustomDialog.<init>(CustomDialog.java:46)
        at com.nileworx.flagsquiz.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:73)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
```

This is my DatabaseHandler.java :

```
package com.nileworx.flagsquiz;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH;

    private static String DB_NAME = "FlagsQuiz";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
     * access to the application assets and resources.
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
        DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString();
//      Log.e("path", DB_PATH);
    }

    // ==============================================================================

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
     * database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {

            // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
            // the default system path
            // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
            // database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
     * time you open the application.
     * 
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            // database does't exist yet.

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    // ==============================================================================

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
     * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
     * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open("database/" + DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the
    // database.
    // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd
    // be easy
    // to you to create adapters for your views.

}
```

And this is my database file directory structure :
[image]

Manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.nileworx.flagsquiz"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.nileworx.flagsquiz.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.nileworx.flagsquiz.UpdatesDialogActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.nileworx.flagsquiz.GameActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.nileworx.flagsquiz.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <service android:name="com.nileworx.flagsquiz.GetUpdatesService" >
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.nileworx.flagsquiz.CheckUpdatesService" >
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

DAO.java

```
public DAO(Context context) {
        dbHandler = new DataBaseHandler(context);
        try {

            dbHandler.createDataBase();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            throw new Error("Unable to create database");

        }
        try {

            dbHandler.openDataBase();

        } catch (SQLException sqle) {

            throw sqle;

        }
        // Log.e("path2",
        // context.getDatabasePath("FootballFlagQuiz").toString());
    }
```

Now how can i solve this issue ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add your manifest file here?

Comment: Have you heard of google room? You can try that if you are open to an easier approach of sqlite

Comment: @LokeshDesai I added it .. check the edit

Comment: Have you handle run time permission for write external storage?

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO Actually i didn't hear about it before .. i want to know first why this error ?? is it about new android api level or what ? because i used this approach for always

Comment: yes from marshmallow u need to handle run time permission also. Refer this https://en.proft.me/2017/06/14/runtime-permissions-android-marshmallow-60-and-abo/

Comment: If you want to trace issue u can manually give permission for external storage from settings screen -> applications. Refer this https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/android-basics-manage-app-permissions-marshmallow-higher-0168220/

Comment: but the device i test on it doesn't have marshmellow .. it is 5.1 (lollipop)

Comment: check out this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17581238/1986282

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO Room is only appropriate to a small set of very simple apps.  You aren't really helping him here.

Comment: @LokeshDesai He's accessing internal storage, not external.  No permission needed.

Comment: @GabeSechan Room is also for complex data, however that was just a suggestion the point being he is trying to checkDatabase before creating one, this might be causing the issue

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO No, it really isn't.  Its horrible for anything where you're doing joins.  And telling someone to rip out their db system and move for a very simple problem isn't helpful.

Comment: @GabeSechan sure, lets solve his problem first. com.nileworx.flagsquiz.DataBaseHandler.checkDataBase(DataBaseHandler.java:86) he is trying to open a database that doesn't exist

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO Also, he'd need to check the db even with room-  he's copying the db from assets to the filesystem if it doesn't exist.  That's something he'd need to do himself under any circumstance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178921/discussion-between-dr-andro-and-gabe-sechan).

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO Yes- because its a fresh install.  Its expected behavior-  his system is set up already to handle it.  This exception isn't a bug.  It will happen the first time he runs his app on any device, and its perfectly ok.

Comment: but i am trying to open it again many times and the app still crashed and forced closed

Comment: Edit your question to include the code that instantiates the DataBaseHandler object, and then tries to access the database (should be `your_handler.createDataBase();`). I believe you may instead be using `your_handler.openDataBase`; which would repeatedly fail.

Comment: added it in main post

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, this is expected.  Its throwing the exception in open in checkDatabase.  Its saying the db file doesn't exist yet.  If this is a new install, that will be true.  You're even coding to expect this-  see your catch statement?  That's how you tell if the db is new.

There's nothing wrong here.  This will print out the first time on any device, and it will still work.  If you want to get rid of the message, take out the logging from your catch statement.

Comment: but i am trying to open it again many times and the app still crashed and forced closed

Comment: Then you have a crash elsewhere.  This is not crashing you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be fine.

I've copied all the code that you've supplied and tried to recreate the errors you are having.

First the stack-trace you show is to be expected, as that is the result of the trapped (caught via catch) that is inevitable when you use (in the `checkDB` method) :-

```
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

and the database doesn't then exist. The stack-trace isn't from a FATAL EXCEPTION. However, the stack-trace itself is issued within the `openDatabase` method so cannot easily be suppressed.

**As such any FATAL EXCEPTION must be elsewhere.** You should check the log further.

Running your code, without a properly named file (e.g. **FlagsQuiz.txt** as opposed to **FlagsQuiz**) results in (note Logging has been added to your code)

i.e. the two files used for testing (extension NOTADB is not an sqlite database, extension txt is a valid sqlite database with the extenstion added) :-

[image]

results in :-

```
08-29 01:01:19.323 2602-2602/? D/CHKDB: Issuing openDatabase for path :- /data/data/so52053932.so52053932/databases/FlagsQuiz
08-29 01:01:19.331 2602-2602/? E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 30174 of [00bb9c9ce4]
    (14) os_unix.c:30174: (2) open(/data/data/so52053932.so52053932/databases/FlagsQuiz) - 
08-29 01:01:19.331 2602-2602/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/so52053932.so52053932/databases/FlagsQuiz'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
        at so52053932.so52053932.DataBaseHandler.checkDataBase(DataBaseHandler.java:89)
        at so52053932.so52053932.DataBaseHandler.createDataBase(DataBaseHandler.java:48)
        at so52053932.so52053932.DAO.<init>(DAO.java:17)
        at so52053932.so52053932.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 01:01:19.331 2602-2602/? D/CHECKDB: SQLiteException has bee caught.
08-29 01:01:19.339 2602-2602/? D/ONCREATE: New Database has been created so ONCREATE has been invoked.
08-29 01:01:19.339 2602-2602/? D/CPYDB: Database Copy Initiated. Trying to open InputStream i.e. asset database/FlagsQuiz
08-29 01:01:19.339 2602-2602/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: database/FlagsQuiz
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:315)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:289)
        at so52053932.so52053932.DataBaseHandler.copyDataBase(DataBaseHandler.java:119)
        at so52053932.so52053932.DataBaseHandler.createDataBase(DataBaseHandler.java:62)
        at so52053932.so52053932.DAO.<init>(DAO.java:17)
        at so52053932.so52053932.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-29 01:01:19.347 2602-2602/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 01:01:19.347 2602-2602/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-29 01:01:19.347 2602-2602/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa62a0288)
08-29 01:01:19.347 2602-2602/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.Error: Error copying database
        at so52053932.so52053932.DataBaseHandler.createDataBase(DataBaseHandler.java:67)
        at so52053932.so52053932.DAO.<init>(DAO.java:17)
        at so52053932.so52053932.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

- There have been 3 Exceptions (the middle, what appears as the 2nd is printing the stack-trace when the final exception has been caught/trapped).
- The first exception is not a FATAL exception and is as explained above (i.e. the expected exception from the `checkDB` method)
- The 2nd exception is the actual exception causing the issue. However, it has been trapped (and due to additional code has been printed, so this wouldn't appear in your code, as it is not printed) this is due in this case to the asset file not being found (i.e. the code is expecting **FlagsQuiz** not **FlagsQuiz.txt** nor **FlagsQuixk.NOTADB**).
- The third exception is as issued by `throw new Error("Error copying database");`
   in the `createDatabase` method. (Not that helpful as in your code the real reason/position in the code is hidden).

**NOTE** At this stage the underlying database has actually been created.**

as per `08-29 01:01:19.339 2602-2602/? D/ONCREATE: New Database has been created so ONCREATE has been invoked.`

e.g. Device Explorer shows :-

As such a subsequent run will not attempt to copy the database from the Assets as one exists. **However**, the database that exists WILL NOT have any tables other than **sqlite_master** and **android_metadata**. That is effectively the database is empty from an application point of view (you'd expect at least 16k (if I recall correctly) as another 4k page for any other table)).

[image]

Therefore, at a guess, your real issue, is another issue. I'd suggest perhaps modifying your code to include temporary debugging as per (SEE **//<<<<<** comments ):-

**DAO.java**

```
public class DAO {

    DataBaseHandler dbHandler;

    public DAO(Context context) {
        dbHandler = new DataBaseHandler(context);
        try {

            dbHandler.createDataBase();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            throw new Error("Unable to create database");

        }
        try {

            dbHandler.openDataBase();
            Log.d("DAO","Attempting to open the database."); //<<<<< ADDED

        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            Log.d("DAOCONSTRUCTOR","Error attempting to Open Database."); //<<<<< ADDED
            sqle.printStackTrace(); //<<<<< ADDED
            throw sqle;
        }
        // Log.e("path2",
        // context.getDatabasePath("FootballFlagQuiz").toString());
    }
}
```

**DataBaseHandler.java**

```
public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // The Androids default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH;

    private static String DB_NAME = "FlagsQuiz";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
     * access to the application assets and resources.
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
        DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString();
//      Log.e("path", DB_PATH);
    }

    // ==============================================================================

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
     * database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {

            // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
            // the default system path
            // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
            // database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); //<<<<< ADDED

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
     * time you open the application.
     *
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH;
            Log.d("CHKDB","Issuing openDatabase for path :- " + myPath); //<<<<< ADDED
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            boolean checkresult = checkDB != null; //<<<<< ADDED
            Log.d("CHKDB", "Result of check is " + String.valueOf(checkresult)); //<<<<< ADDED

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.d("CHECKDB", "SQLiteException has bee caught."); //<<<<< ADDED

            // database does't exist yet.

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {
            Log.d("CHECKDB","DB exists so closing the opened DB."); //<<<<< ADDED
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    // ==============================================================================

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
     * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
     * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        Log.d("CPYDB","Database Copy Initiated. Trying to open InputStream i.e. asset " + "database/" + DB_NAME); //<<<<< ADDED

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open("database/" + DB_NAME);
        Log.d("CPYDB","InputStream Opened successfully. Now trying to open OutputStream path = " + DB_PATH); //<<<<< ADDED

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        Log.d("CPYDB","OutputStream Opened successfully. Now trying to copy from InputStream to OutputStream."); //<<<<< ADDED

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            Log.d("CPYDB","Copied " + String.valueOf(length) + " bytes."); //<<<<< ADDED
        }
        Log.d("CPYDB","Completed Copy from asset to DB. Flusing and closing Streams"); //<<<<< ADDED

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
        Log.d("CPYDB","Copy complete and all sterams flushed and closed. Copied " + String.valueOf(length) + "bytes."); //<<<<< ADDED
    }

    // ==============================================================================

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d("ONCREATE","New Database has been created so ONCREATE has been invoked."); //<<<<< ADDED

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the
    // database.
    // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd
    // be easy
    // to you to create adapters for your views.

}
```

With the above changes and perhaps a better understanding of stack-traces you will be able to pin-point the real error(s) that you are encountering.

---

#### Valid Run

Running your code with a valid DB in the assets file and using the following as the (invoking) `MainActivity` :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DAO myDAO;
    DataBaseHandler myDBhandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDAO = new DAO(this);
        myDBhandler = myDAO.dbHandler;
        SQLiteDatabase db = myDBhandler.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor csr = db.query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("COMPONENTS","Found " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("name")) + " Type is " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("type")));
        }
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

results in :-

```
08-29 01:14:06.139 2699-2699/? D/CHKDB: Issuing openDatabase for path :- /data/data/so52053932.so52053932/databases/FlagsQuiz
08-29 01:14:06.139 2699-2699/? E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 30174 of [00bb9c9ce4]
    (14) os_unix.c:30174: (2) open(/data/data/so52053932.so52053932/databases/FlagsQuiz) - 
08-29 01:14:06.139 2699-2699/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/so52053932.so52053932/databases/FlagsQuiz'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
        at so52053932.so52053932.DataBaseHandler.checkDataBase(DataBaseHandler.java:89)
        at so52053932.so52053932.DataBaseHandler.createDataBase(DataBaseHandler.java:48)
        at so52053932.so52053932.DAO.<init>(DAO.java:17)
        at so52053932.so52053932.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 01:14:06.139 2699-2699/? D/CHECKDB: SQLiteException has bee caught.
08-29 01:14:06.151 2699-2699/? D/ONCREATE: New Database has been created so ONCREATE has been invoked.
08-29 01:14:06.151 2699-2699/? D/CPYDB: Database Copy Initiated. Trying to open InputStream i.e. asset database/FlagsQuiz
    InputStream Opened successfully. Now trying to open OutputStream path = /data/data/so52053932.so52053932/databases/FlagsQuiz
    OutputStream Opened successfully. Now trying to copy from InputStream to OutputStream.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Copied 1024 bytes.
    Completed Copy from asset to DB. Flusing and closing Streams
    Copy complete and all sterams flushed and closed. Copied -1bytes.
08-29 01:14:06.151 2699-2699/? D/DAO: Attempting to open the database.
08-29 01:14:06.159 2699-2699/? D/COMPONENTS: Found android_metadata Type is table
    Found PrivateList Type is table
    Found PrivateProduct Type is table
    Found List_Product Type is table
    Found sqlite_autoindex_List_Product_1 Type is index
```

### Alternative DB Check

The following code is an alternative method that checks if the DB exists (assumes a valid DB) without issuing the SQLiteException. i.e. it checks the DB file rather than the DB (*it will also not create an empty database should the copy fail*):-

```
private boolean ifDatabaseExists(String dbpath) {
    File db = new File(dbpath);
    if(db.exists()) return true;
    File dir = new File(db.getParent());
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    return false;
}
```

- this could be used as an alternative to the `checkDB` method.